# Is it possible to further optimize this qb writer?

Tags: python, scripting, optimization

I have this QB writer and it runs quite ok but takes longer when bigger files are written. I was wondering if there are any libraries out there or anything in this script that can be optimized to make it faster?

```
import struct

from mathutils import Color
from typing import List, Dict, Tuple

class QbMatrix:
    def __init__(self, name: str, data: List[List[List[Tuple[int, int, int, int]]]], pos: Tuple[int, int, int]):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = pos
        self.data = data

class Qb:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.version: int = 0x0101
        self.colorFormat: int = 0
        self.zAxisOrientation: int = 0
        self.compressed: int = 0
        self.visibilityMaskEncoded: int = 0
        self.matrixList: List[QbMatrix] = []

    def add_matrix(self, name: str, data: List[List[List[Tuple[int, int, int, int]]]], pos: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.matrixList.append(QbMatrix(name, data, pos))

    def save(self, filename: str) -> None:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f: # type(f) = <class '_io.BufferedWriter'>
            self.compressed = 0  # Compression saving not supported

            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.version))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.colorFormat))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.zAxisOrientation))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.compressed))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.visibilityMaskEncoded))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", len(self.matrixList)))

            for matrix in self.matrixList: # QbMatrix
                self.save_matrix(f, matrix)

    def save_matrix(self, file: object, matrix: QbMatrix) -> None:
        file.write(struct.pack("B", len(matrix.name)))
        file.write(struct.pack(str(len(matrix.name.encode('ascii')))+"s", matrix.name.encode('ascii')))
        size_x = len(matrix.data)
        size_y = len(matrix.data[0])
        size_z = len(matrix.data[0][0])
        file.write(struct.pack("III", size_x, size_y, size_z))
        file.write(struct.pack("iii", matrix.pos[0], matrix.pos[1], matrix.pos[2]))
        for z in range(size_z):
            for y in range(size_y):
                for x in range(size_x):
                    color = matrix.data[x][y][z]
                    file.write(struct.pack("BBBB", color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]))
```

Here's a sample usage:

```
def test_write_qb() -> None:
    EMPTY_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    data: List[List[List[Tuple[int, int, int, int]]]] = []
    colors: Dict[Tuple[int, int, int], Color] = {(-2, -1, -2): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (-1, -1, -1): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (-2, 0, -1): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (-1, -1, -2): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (-1, -1, 0): Color((204.0, 7.0, 2.0)), (0, -1, 1): Color((204.0, 7.0, 2.0)), (-2, 0, -2): Color((120.0, 116.0, 91.0)), (-1, 1, -2): Color((79.0, 77.0, 56.0)), (-1, 1, -1): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (-1, 0, -2): Color((90.0, 86.0, 59.0)), (-1, 0, 0): Color((204.0, 7.0, 2.0)), (0, -1, -2): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (0, -1, -1): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (0, -1, 0): Color((204.0, 7.0, 2.0)), (0, 0, -2): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (0, 0, -1): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (0, 1, -2): Color((0.0, 204.0, 0.0)), (0, 0, 0): Color((204.0, 7.0, 2.0))}

    for x in range(-3, 3 + 1):
        layer: List[List[Tuple[int, int, int, int]]] = []
        for y in range(-3, 3 + 1):
            row: List[Tuple[int, int, int, int]] = []
            for z in range(-3, 3 + 1):
                color: Color = colors.get((x, y, z))
                if color:
                    row.append((int(color.r), int(color.g), int(color.b), 255))
                else:
                    row.append(EMPTY_COLOR)
            layer.append(row)
        data.append(layer)

    file: str = "C:/out.qb"
    layer: QbMatrix = QbMatrix("cube", data, (0, 0, 0))

    qb: Qb = Qb()
    qb.matrixList.append(layer)
    qb.save(file)

import time
start = time.time()
test_write_qb()
print("time taken is", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: I think you should use `multithreading`.

Comment: first i would like to know if it's possible to further optimize without multithreading :)

Comment: do you have a quite bigger qb file example?

Comment: @lemon is [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U-ZdrX_sUBTC1gI1aOxuJX2F5oE_rXnO/view?usp=sharing) ok? just assign this to the colors dictionary. This one takes 2 seconds on my slow machine. How about yours?

Comment: Megan, in mean time, I've randomly generated data. Which dimensions do you target in X, Y, Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expect around 30 to 50% of performance gain flattening the data array.

The QB matrix should receive a flat array of colors and the voxel dimensions in X, Y, Z. So that we can write all the data in one step instead of looping and writing each time.

```
class QbMatrix:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size_x, size_y, size_z, data, pos: Tuple[int, int, int]):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = pos
        self.data = data
        self.size_x = size_x
        self.size_y = size_y
        self.size_z = size_z
        
class Qb:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.version: int = 0x0101
        self.colorFormat: int = 0
        self.zAxisOrientation: int = 0
        self.compressed: int = 0
        self.visibilityMaskEncoded: int = 0
        self.matrixList: List[QbMatrix] = []

    def add_matrix(self, name: str, data, pos: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.matrixList.append(QbMatrix(name, data, pos))

    def save(self, filename: str) -> None:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f: # type(f) = <class '_io.BufferedWriter'>
            self.compressed = 0  # Compression saving not supported

            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.version))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.colorFormat))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.zAxisOrientation))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.compressed))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.visibilityMaskEncoded))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", len(self.matrixList)))

            for matrix in self.matrixList: # QbMatrix
                self.save_matrix(f, matrix)

    def save_matrix(self, file: object, matrix: QbMatrix) -> None:
        file.write(struct.pack("B", len(matrix.name)))
        file.write(struct.pack(str(len(matrix.name.encode('ascii')))+"s", matrix.name.encode('ascii')))
        size_x = matrix.size_x
        size_y = matrix.size_y
        size_z = matrix.size_z
        file.write(struct.pack("III", size_x, size_y, size_z))
        file.write(struct.pack("iii", matrix.pos[0], matrix.pos[1], matrix.pos[2]))

        file.write(bytes([c for color in matrix.data for c in color]))
```

The key point is in the last line above. It packs once for all the colors and write once to the file.

Concerning the other part of the code, you can:

```
def get_ranges(colors):
    coords = list(colors.keys())
    min_x, min_y, min_z = coords[0]
    max_x, max_y, max_z = coords[0]
    for c in coords:
        x, y, z = c
        min_x = min(min_x, x)
        min_y = min(min_y, y)
        min_z = min(min_z, z)
        max_x = max(max_x, x)
        max_y = max(max_y, y)
        max_z = max(max_z, z)
    return min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z

def test_write_qb(size_x, size_y, size_z, colors) -> None:
    EMPTY_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 0)

    min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z = get_ranges(colors)

    data = [(*colors[(x,y,z)], 1) if colors.get((x,y,z)) else EMPTY_COLOR 
                for x in range(min_x, max_x + 1)
                for y in range(min_y, max_y + 1)
                for z in range(min_z, max_z + 1)]

    write(size_x, size_y, size_z, data)

def write(size_x, size_y, size_z, data):
    file: str = "D:/temp/out.qb"
    layer: QbMatrix = QbMatrix("cube", size_x, size_y, size_z, data, (0, 0, 0))

    qb: Qb = Qb()
    qb.matrixList.append(layer)
    qb.save(file)
```

To avoid loops again, but this is not really significant in terms of perf.

Please check if I've not inverted things for X, Y, Z order (I cannot check it as I don't have Qubicle)

**Important**: `colors` parameter above should be a dictionary of (x,y,z) to a (r, g, b) tuple representing the color (not a `Color` instance).

Concerning multithreading, as the key point is writting to a file, I don't think that can be interesting to multithread data generation (even if it was possible here).

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151969/discussion-on-answer-by-lemon-is-it-possible-to-further-optimize-this-qb-writer); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.